# How to pass a table from a column layout to a line layout in R?

Tags: r, layout, line

I have an R table on a column layout. In the picture it's the left one. And I would like to put it on a line layout, it would look like the right table.

My idea is to create a table without the column net and a table without the ceded. 
I change the field's names net and ceded with amount.
Then i create a column with the id for both of them. 
Then I append them.

But is there an shorter way to do this ?

Thanks in advance, 
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha0jl.png)

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and using some created data since I didn't want to get the data from your pictures:

```r
> data
  year      net    ceded
1    1 266.73007 317.6823
2    2 729.50176 366.0213
3    3 425.06088 162.0960
4    4 723.09221 348.2421
5    5  45.05688 467.0686
6    6  44.78075 154.3635
7    7  59.73864 750.4060
8    8 526.06015 585.1687
9    9 229.78809 554.1722
10  10 355.92545 232.5220
```

Now we want to transform those data into a "longer" format:

```r
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(net, ceded), names_to="id", values_to="amount")
```

yields

```r
# A tibble: 20 x 3
    year id    amount
   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1 net    267. 
 2     1 ceded  318. 
 3     2 net    730. 
 4     2 ceded  366. 
 5     3 net    425. 
 6     3 ceded  162. 
 7     4 net    723. 
 8     4 ceded  348. 
 9     5 net     45.1
10     5 ceded  467. 
11     6 net     44.8
12     6 ceded  154. 
13     7 net     59.7
14     7 ceded  750. 
15     8 net    526. 
16     8 ceded  585. 
17     9 net    230. 
18     9 ceded  554. 
19    10 net    356. 
20    10 ceded  233.
```

An alternative using `reshape2`:

```r
data %>%
  melt(id.vars=c("year"), measure.vars=c("net", "ceded"))
```